# how to use stdout save image in Rust?

Tags: rust

In my terminal command the `adb shell screencap -p | sed 's/\r$//' > screen.png` it is work, save my android screen.

I know can use `adb pull`, but I want to know how to use stdout way save an image in Rust? So, I try this code, buy can't open the image. There may be a problem on encoding, but I don't know how to fix them

```
    let output = Command::new("adb")
            .arg("shell")
            .arg("screencap -p")
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process");

    let byte_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout).replace("\r\n","\n");


    let byte_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
    let mut buffer = File::create("foo.png")?;

    buffer.write(&byte_string.as_bytes())?;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to *include the error* you are getting.

Answer (score 4):

Image data is binary, not a Unicode string. So you need to print a `&[u8]` and not a UTF-8 `String`.

```
let out = std::io::stdout();
out.write_all(slice)?;
out.flush()?;
```

The `flush` is necessary since `write_all` immediately followed by a program exit fails to deliver the bytes to the underlying file descriptor.

Since rust has no string processing for u8 arrays you need to undo the adb mangling manually by iterating over the bytes and checking whether the current one is \r and the next is \n and then skip the current one.

Comment: How would OP perform the replacement of `\r` they wish to make?

Comment: that just skips the last byte it seems